# How to use Perl to change a mysql password

Tags: mysql, perl

I need to change a few mysql passwords using a Perl script.  The following works when changing database entries, but when I modified it for mysql user changes, it resets them to a blank password.  It would also be nice to 'flush privileges' at the end of it, but I haven't found the method for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

my $newpass = "newpass";
my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "mysql";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, 'root', 'mysql' ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("update user set password='$newpass' where User='admin'");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a couple of steps.
Use the PASSWORD() command and used 'admin' and not 'root' and also add flush priv's. 
I rewrote the script for you, here:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

my $newpass = "newpass";
my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "mysql";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, 'root', 'mysql' ) or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->{AutoCommit} = 0;
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("update user set password=PASSWORD('$newpass') where User='root'");
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;
$dbh->do('FLUSH PRIVILEGES') or die $DBI::errstr;
$sth->finish();
$dbh->commit or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-password.html) syntax:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("update user set password='$newpass' where User='admin'");
```

Into this:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("update mysql.user set Password=Password('$newpass') 
                         where User='admin' and Host='localhost'");
```

Comment: That did it.  I still have to run 'flush privileges' for the change to take effect, though.

Comment: can you explain why you added the host specification?

Comment: @msouth , i added the Host specification, because in some cases there is more than one account with the same name(example: admin@localhost, admin@127.0.0.1, admin@remoteip, etc)

Comment: ok, but how did you know the questioner wanted the one for localhost?

Comment: I doesn't know...but this way is more secure, and you could be sure that the update is made in just one account