# PHP/PDO - How do I change password of logged in user via PHP and PDO and refresh connection handle?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Scenario**

I am trying to change the username of the current logged in mysql user via PDO and PHP and am unable to alter the password for the logged in user (in the mysql user table).

*I can change this only in my application users table, for which I want to use the same password.*

**Note**

I am successfully able to change this via the mysql command line (Windows Command Prompt) but when I try to change this via my PHP script (changePassword) the old password remains.

**Question**

How can I alter the password in PHP/PDO?

```
    public function changePassword($username, $password, $password1, $password2)
    {
        $userPassExists = $this->confirmUserNamePassword($username, $password);
        if ($userPassExists)
        {
            if ($password1 == '' or $password2 == '')
            {
                echo "Complete all entries";
            }
            else if ($password1 != $password2)
            {
                echo "New Passwords must match";
            }
            else
            {
                    $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE users set password = ':password' where username = ':username'");
                    $sql->execute(array(':password' => $this->createPwdHash($password1), ':username' => $username));


                    $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD(':password') WHERE user=':username' AND Host='localhost';");
                    $sql->execute(array(':username', $username, ':password' => $password1));

                    $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("flush privileges");
                    $sql->execute();

                    $this->dbh = null;
                    $this->dbh = $this->getConnection($username, $password1);
                    var_dump($this->dbh);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
        }
    }
```

EDIT

Following the syntax from the link below, I modified my function to the code below, but now it produces a warning.

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter
>   number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in
>   script.php on line 191

Line 191 is

```
 $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("set password for :username@'localhost' = PASSWORD(:password)");
```

**Link**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22721480/1691103

```
    public function changePassword($username, $password, $password1, $password2)
    {
        $userPassExists = $this->confirmUserNamePassword($username, $password);
        if ($userPassExists)
        {
            if ($password1 == '' or $password2 == '')
            {
                echo "Complete all entries";
            }
            else if ($password1 != $password2)
            {
                echo "New Passwords must match";
            }
            else
            {
                    $this->resetPassword($username, $password1);
                    $this->dbh = null;
                    $this->dbh = $this->getConnection($username, $password1);
                    var_dump($this->dbh);
            }
        }
        else
        {
                echo "Incorrect Username or Password";
        }
    }


    public function resetPassword($username, $password)
    {
            $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE users set password = :password where username = :username");
            $sql->execute(array(':password' => $this->createPwdHash($password), ':username' => $username));

            $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("set password for :username@'localhost' = PASSWORD(:password)");
            $sql->execute(array(':username', $username, ':password' => $password));
    }
```

Comment: Does the mysql user you're connecting to the db with have permissions to change mysql user passwords?

Comment: I have actually granted update privilege to the users table before hand.  If this is not a good way of going about it I will need to change my approach.

Comment: Oh I see. When you are using parameterized queries you do not put `'` around the placeholders.  So its just `:password` not `':password'`. Same for `:username`. That's probably your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I removed the quotes around the prepared queries but it seems not able to change to the new password.  I'll give it another shot.

Comment: I modified the question with updated code.  I seem to be getting closer but it still is unable to complete the change of password.

Comment: My apologies, I did not carefully inspect the syntax.  My array key value is not correctly formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execute command

```
 $sql->execute(array(':username', $username, ':password' => $password1));
```

Should Read

```
 $sql->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password1));
```